# how can I use just post codes to calculate travel time using MapsApi in Rstudio

Tags: r

Error in encode_locations(origins) : object 'encoded' not found

this error msg was generated when I try to use MapsApi package in Rstudio to calculate the driving time, below is what I tried to put in... ...

```r
locations <- experiment_api_Sheet1
doc = mp_matrix(origins = locations, destinations = "10019", mode = "driving",
                departure_time = Sys.time() + as.difftime(1, units = "mins"),
                key = readLines("~/key"))
```

Comment: I think this is a [new bug](https://github.com/michaeldorman/mapsapi/issues/new) in the `mapsapi` package. The [`encode_locations`](https://github.com/cran/mapsapi/blob/f4bb95e0859409d574f25756a8e4e19ff71686b7/R/encode_locations.R) function is poorly written such that `encoded` is only defined if the input is one of four classes; instead of producing an error if that assumption is not met, it tries to return an object that was never created. Regardless, I'll guess that your `locations` is not one of the intended formats. (I may be wrong. Since we know nothing of your data, it's a guess.)

Comment: I was just trying anyway, basically, I faked a .csv with a bunch of postcodes in there and tried to test out if this package can give me a summarization of travel durations from different postcode locations (since google map is ok with me to just typeing in the postcodes to ask derections)

Comment: do you think assigning area names to postcodes will resolve the problems?

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like or what you expect to get in return. Further, I'm not familiar with the `mapsapi` package, so I don't know for certain if what you're trying to do is supported. I suggest you make this question reproducible by adding sample data; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.